# links CSS doesn't change on click event on iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, safari

When an `<a>` element is clicked on, normally it changes it's color or something to indicate it has been clicked. I just noticed that in iPhone's Safari, the CSS attribute change of a link upon click doesn't take place and the page just seems to not be responding, then it redirects to the link's URL properly, but the user will think that the link is broken because of this. Has anyone seen this problem? Have you been able to workaround it?

I have compared my website to others and it's kind of common. I have also tried a couple of things with javascript, but seems that the CSS changes are ignored and the link redirects before changing the CSS in the link. This doesn't happen on other browsers like Chrome in Android. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this css rule fix the problem: `cursor: pointer;` Ohterwise post some code.

Comment: Did you setup *:visited* property on your link tag?

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS `a:visited { color: red !important; }`. Change the color to what you want but this apple discussion might help https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2727531?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Post some more code to show us what you have done. Otherwise, all the answers here are just guesses.